# Error about CORS when anuglar accesses my-json-server on stackblitz

Tags: angular, json-server

On stackblitz, I built an Angular project to access `my-json-server` mock server.
[**It's here.**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-test-cors?file=app/app.component.ts)

Once clicking `Send Request` button, I got the following error on console:

> Failed to load https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts/1: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://angular-http-test-cors.stackblitz.io' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The error asks me to  set the request's mode to 'no-cors'.
But how to achieve this?
Should I change the configuration on my-json-server? But how?
Could I just change my program?

**References:**
[Requesting services from a different server (CORS)](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#requesting-services-from-a-different-server-cors)

**UPTATE:20180314**
I tried it today. Nothing is done, it can work now. Weird!

Comment: CORS is something that needs to be fixed (configured) on the server. The server needs to return the mentioned headers, otherwise the browser refused to make the actual request. To get suggestions how to fix it's necessary to know what kind of server you are using. The chances are huge there are already answers to that question. This is one of the most frequently asked questions.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer you're right. I want to know if I can use the live running my-json-server. I don't know if I can change that server configuration.

Comment: I don't know what `my-json-server` is or what it is built with. You'll get an OPTIONS request from the server and the server needs to respond to this request with the mentioned headers. If the browser gets the expected response, it will make the actual (GET, POST, ...) request.

Comment: I'm using this, https://my-json-server.typicode.com/

Answer (score 0):

I tried your [URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-test-cors?file=app/app.component.ts) in chrome and that happened, you may try it again and if it fails just open up "Developer Tools" and in Network tab you see some of the requests failed, check mark the "Disable cache" and refresh, it shows up.